# How to write a regex for this case?

Tags: java, regex

I like to know how to write a regex for the following code.

```
<a href="/search?q=user:111111+[apple]" class="post-tag" title="show all posts by this user in 'apple'">Apple</a><span class="item-multiplier">&times;&nbsp;171</span><br>
```

I just need to fetch Apple from the above source code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: KennyTM, while it's true that you can't parse HTML using regex, this question is not about parsing HTML but rather parsing an a tag, which is certainly possible.

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent tool at [txt2re](http://txt2re.com/index-java.php3) that can be used to EASILY generate regexp in various languages.
I used it to [generate](http://txt2re.com/index-java.php3?s=%3Ca%20href=%22/search?q=user:111111%2b[apple]%22%20class=%22post-tag%22%20title=%22show%20all%20posts%20by%20this%20user%20in%20%27apple%27%22%3EApple%3C/a%3E%3Cspan%20class=%22item-multiplier%22%3E%26times;%26nbsp;171%3C/span%3E%3Cbr%3E&21) the following:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String txt="<a href=\"/search?q=user:111111+[apple]\" class=\"post-tag\" title=\"show all posts by this user in 'apple'\">Apple</a><span class=\"item-multiplier\">&times;&nbsp;171</span><br>";

    String re1=".*?";   // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re2="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";   // Uninteresting: word
    String re3=".*?";   // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re4="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";   // Uninteresting: word
    String re5=".*?";   // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re6="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";   // Uninteresting: word
    String re7=".*?";   // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re8="((?:[a-z][a-z]+))"; // Word 1

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5+re6+re7+re8,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(txt);
    if (m.find())
    {
        String word1=m.group(1);
        System.out.print("("+word1.toString()+")"+"\n");
    }
  }
}
```